# Getting whole Line containing specific word using Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a txt file containing sentences like:

```
When I move to this page
Then It display poup
......
......
```

so i want to get lines only contains "Then" keyword at starting using Regular Expression

Comment: here it is `@"^Then.*`for case insensitive match `@"(?i)^Then.*"`

Comment: @Avinash :Thanks for your suggestion.one thing more i want to ask suppose i have 5000 lines containing word like "When","Then","And"... so  getting lines by using Regular Expression will give me faster solution or Linq

Comment: did you want all the files which startswith `When`, `Then` and `And` then try this `@"^(?:When|Then|And).*"`

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done using `string.StartsWith` method via LINQ:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("path")
                .Where(line => line.StartsWith("Then"))
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want or need Regex for this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(l => l.StartsWith("Then"));
```

Comment: Just to add OP, if you want case insensitive matching, you can use the overloaded method `l.StartsWith("Then", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`